# Created App in Production produces FeatureNotAvailable

Tags: api, sms, ringcentral

We just moved our app from Sandbox to production. We have no issue with sending SMS to any number in Sandbox but it's not working when we switched to production.

Here's the error:
Exception: The requested feature is not available SDK HTTP Error at https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/sms Response text: { "errorCode" : "FeatureNotAvailable", "message" : "The requested feature is not available", "errors" : [ { "errorCode" : "MSG-242", "message" : "The requested feature is not available" } ] }
What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give a little more background information so I can help?
1/ Does the from phone number belong to the extension you logged in?
2/ Is the phone number a toll-free number?

Some code snippet and programming language/SDK could be helpful too.